# How do I access the column names of a view datasource in sortColumn?

Tags: xpages

I have a custom control that displays a view based off some configuration documents. We had been storing the sortColumn in a sessionScope variable, so that the user could retain the sort when they leave and return to the Xpage. Unfortunately, if they leave for another Xpage that has the same custom control, but for which the view doesn't have a column by the same name, it throws an error.

So, I thought I could check the columnNames of the view so that we don't try using a sortColumn that doesn't exist. I have been unable to get a handle to the view data source while also applying the sortColumn.

```
<xp:dominoView var="inputView" sortOrder="#javascript:sessionScope.sortedColumnDirection}">
    <xp:this.sortColumn><![CDATA[#{javascript:var nameVector:java.util.Vector = inputView.getColumnNames();
        var nameArray = sessionScope.curDynamicViewSettings.columnTitles;
            if ( @IsMember(viewScope.sortedColumnName,nameArray)) {
                return viewScope.sortedColumnName;
            }
        return;}]]>
    </xp:this.sortColumn>
</xp:dominoView>
```

Comment: I've implement the same function a while ago, and saving the last sortcolumn per accessed view in the sessionScope was a lot easier. But it depends on how many views your users open and sort per session ofcource.

Comment: The hurdle is that if the columnName doesn't exist in the next view, it throws an error. I guess I could put the view name into the sessionScope variable so that it only sorts by a column specified for that view. Actually, the hurdle in all of it is getting a handle to the view so we can tell the view name or column names....

Comment: David, Ferry suggested to save the sort column **per** view. Storing only one variable is asking for trouble. With an object you don't use ViewA sort column when calling ViewB